# Sencha 2.0 title bar is overlapped with select all range area

Tags: javascript, css, ios6, webkit, sencha-touch-2

Sencha 2.0 title bar is overlapped with select all range area if edit area with entered text is scrolled up it's running on IOS  6.1 safari (webkit) 
[image: here]

This is the way we are defining the view for new message creation dialog

```
{
xtype: 'panel',
name: 'createMsgPanel',
id:'createMsgPanel',
cls:'newMsg-panel',
width: 840,
top:0,
left: 100,
modal: true,
hideAnimation: 'fadeOut',  // slideOut
hideOnMaskTap: false,
hidden: true,
items: [
{
xtype:'panel',
id:'createMsgPanelDiv',
cls:'nativeScrollingCls',
layout: 'vbox',
items:[
{
    xtype: 'formpanel',
    scrollable: false,
    height: 170,
    name: 'headerForm',
    items:[{
 xtype : 'emailfield',
 name : 'SenderEmail',
 id : 'senderEmail',
 label : 'To:',
 labelWidth : 38,
 height:35
    }, {
 xtype : 'emailfield',
 name : 'Cc',
 id : 'cc',
 label : 'Cc:',
 labelWidth : 38,
 height: 35
    }, {
 xtype: 'emailfield',
 name: 'Bcc',
 id: 'bcc',
 label: 'Bcc:',
 labelWidth: 42,
 height: 35
    }, {
 xtype : 'textfield',
 name : 'Subject',
 id : 'subject',
 label : 'Subject:',
 labelWidth : 74,
 height: 35
    },
 {
     xtype: 'container',
     layout: 'hbox',
     name: 'AttachmentsOuter',
     items: [
  {
      xtype: 'label',
      html: 'Attachments:',
      name : 'AttachmentsLabel',
      style: 'font-weight: bold; font-size: .8em; margin: 3px 0px 0px 10px;',
      width : 110
  },
  {
      xtype : 'panel',
      cls: 'att',
      name : 'Attachments',
      label : 'Attachments:',
      labelWidth : 130,
      width: 700,
      style: 'font-size: .8em; margin-top:7px'
  },
  {
      xtype: 'container',
      style: 'display: none',
      name: 'AttachmentsValue'
  }
     ]
 }

    ]
},{
    xtype: 'container',
    name: 'emailEditAreaCt',
    id: 'emailEditAreaCt',
    flex: 1,
    html: '<textarea id="inputEdit" style="width:825px;height:180px"></textarea>'

}
]
},{
    xtype: 'titlebar',   // Here we are defining titlebar
    name: 'newMsgTBar',
    title: 'New Message',
    docked: 'top',
    items: [{
 text: 'Cancel',
 name: 'cancel',
 align: 'left',
 margin: '0 10 0 0'
    },{
 text: 'Send',
 name: 'send',
 align: 'right',
 disabled: 'true'
    },{
 html:'<input type="text" id="dummyEmailTextBox" style="width:20px;background-color:transparent;border:none;"/>',
 ui:"plain",
 style:'-webkit-box-shadow: none;height:0px;left:-230px'
    }]

},{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    name: 'editorToolBar',
    docked: 'bottom',
    height:35,
    html: '<div class="newMsg-important" id="emailImpDiv" ><div class="newMsg-important-image"></div></div>' +
  '<div class="newMsg-important-low" id="emailLowImpDiv" ><div class="newMsg-important-low-image"></div></div>' +
  '<div id="inputEditPanel" style="width:769px;display:inline;float:left;"></div>'
}
]
}
```

what solution would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason for using `<input type='text'.../>` instead of Sencha's proper [textarea](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.field.TextArea)? If you use normal form fields you can define a fieldset with those fields and add it in `vbox` layout with docked toolbar, and that should work

Comment: actually this item html:'<input type="text" id="dummyEmailTextBox"... is hidden and used for some focus actions, real editor is added in container below xtype: 'container',
    name: 'emailEditAreaCt',
    id: 'emailEditAreaCt',
    flex: 1,
    html: '<textarea id="inputEdit" style="width:825px;height:180px"></textarea>'